# Does IE11 has size limitation on innerHTML?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, innerhtml

We have a web application which calls a third party Web API which returns a PDF binary. We put that PDF binary in "innerHTML" property of a  element. We then pass this content of "innerHTML" to another JavaScript based API so that the content can be print silently. The solution works fine for smaller PDF but is not working when the PDF size goes beyond 8 MB. In IE11, if the PDF size is smaller than 8MB then it is working fine but if it is larger than 8MB then we are getting "Error: Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation". The same solution working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Edge etc. Does IE11 has size limitation on innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the upper limit of web cache and database is 10MB in IE. You could view the cache through these steps below: **Tools > Internet Options > General tab > Settings > Caches and databases** tab. You can also refer to this similar case appropriately: [IE 11 throws not enough storage is available to complete this operation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/24f8378a-83a0-471a-97af-bebbe25eb92f/ie-11-throws-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation?forum=iewebdevelopment).

You need to test from a domain uri, use Internet Options to delete existing entries and clear the localStorage.
And there are differences for various browsers, you could also refer to this article:  [Storage for the web](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/).